# Git Add, Git Commit, and Git Push

Tags: git, github

Can any of you pros please educate me on what the main differences are between git add, git commit, and git push, and when do you decide what to use? I understand the purpose is to ultimately save them in your repository but I'm still confused as to how they are being used.

Comment: If you `commit` without doing `add`, nothing happens because nothing has been added to "staging" aka "the index". If you `push` without doing `commit`, nothing happens because there is no local commit to push to the upstream remote. `git status` is also important, it shows you what is not added and what is added. `git log` is also important, it shows you what has been commited and what has been pushed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are new to git.. Let me explain them in a way you understand.

First you need to understand, there are three areas: ***Working directory***, ***staging area***, ***repository***.

- **Working directory** is the place you are working in, i.e, your
  folder/files.
- **Staging area** is the intermediate stage between your working directory
  and repository. You stage the required files here before you commit
  to the repository.
- And the **reopsitory** is the .git folder where all your commits are stored

`git add <files>` is used to transfer your files in the working directory to the staging area.

`git commit` is used to move those files in the staging area to the repo by making a commit.

`git push` is something different. It do not make changes to your local git repo, but instead it will transfer your entire git repo to a cloud hosting service like github, gitlab, etc.....